# How to use Grand Central Dispatch in iOS in a .c file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, foundation, grand-central-dispatch

I have some C code in an iOS project that I would like to optimize using GCD. Currently I can only get my code to compile if change my C file to an Objective-C file and import the Foundation framework. What do I have to include in my C file to get access to GCD?

I've tried:

```
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
```

but that doesn't seem to work it always complains about code blocks having the ^ character

Comment: What version of xcode / compiler are you using? What is your target platform version?

Comment: Xcode version 3.2.4 and my target platform is iOS 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to tell the compiler to enable Blocks with the `-fblocks` flag. You'll also need to use a compiler that understands blocks (Clang, for one).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to;

```
#include <Block.h>
```

But it's not something I've done myself so could be wrong here.